# Suspicious SSH process

Tags: linux, ssh

today I found a running ssh process that was not there a few days ago. Can anyone know what this ist doing?

```
ssh -x -a -oClearAllForwardings=yes -2 ssh@172.30.0.56 -s sftp
```

Comment: Look in your `last` log, syslog and potentially audit.log's for who may have logged in and started that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the command that actually gets run when someone runs `sftp`.

In this case someone has run `sftp ssh@172.30.0.56`, which spawns this process to handle the actual connection.

Comment: Any chance to see where it came from?

Comment: @Gewürzwiesel Try something like `ps auxf`.

Comment: Oh my... How embarrassing... I have a running sshfs Session. That explains it. Many thanks!